# varchar number starting with +

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying below to find out if the column (dis_num) value is numeric or not which is working fine.

`REGEXP_LIKE(dis_num, '^[[:digit:]]+$')`

Now dis_num column can starts with + and then numbers like +8143434344. How to modify above regex which is consider starting with + as well ? Means if column has number starting with + then also we need to consider as numeric.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check for a literal `+` sign you can escape it; and can make it optional with `?`

```
REGEXP_LIKE(dis_num, '^\+?[[:digit:]]+$')
```

Very quick demo:

```
with t (dis_num) as (
  select '1234' from dual
  union all select 'abc' from dual
  union all select '+8143434344' from dual
)
select dis_num,
  case when REGEXP_LIKE(dis_num, '^[[:digit:]]+$') then 'Yes' else 'No' end as check1,
  case when REGEXP_LIKE(dis_num, '^\+?[[:digit:]]+$') then 'Yes' else 'No' end as check2
from t;

DIS_NUM     CHE CHE
----------- --- ---
1234        Yes Yes
abc         No  No 
+8143434344 No  Yes
```

Comment: I agree with Alex, who beat me to posting by 35 seconds, the other answer will give you false positives if you just use replace as it will replace the '+' anywhere in the string, not just the beginning.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Poole for answer. I really liked it.

Answer (score 1):

AS Littlefoot says you need to replace + then evaluate the string.

You can also uses TRANSLATE, I think it's pretty useful to create a function in any oracle DB that you can call anywhere like this:

```
  FUNCTION only_numbers(p_value VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN(TRANSLATE(p_value , '1' || TRANSLATE(p_value , 'a1234567890', 'a'), '1'));
  END only_numbers;
```

> SELECT only_numbers(dis_num)     FROM your_table should work too.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `+` first, then check it:

```
REGEXP_LIKE(replace(dis_num, '+', ''), '^[[:digit:]]+$')
            -------------------------
```

Comment: This would remove the `+` as positions other than the first position.

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot for answer.